# Foundation navigation top-bar not working with thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I have an HTML template file which uses Spring MVC + thymeleaf and I'm trying to create a navigable menu at the top of the page using Foundation's "top-bar" component.

So far, the menu bar is displayed but menus are not being shown when the cursor is placed on top.

I can display the sub-menus related to my main menu options (the ones placed at the bar) but sub-menus are not working because when I click an option on the first sub-menu, the menu closes instead of displaying another sub-menu.

My HTML file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/foundation.min.css}" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="top-bar" role="navigation" data-topbar="true">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="left">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#"><span th:text="#{menu.administration}"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#"><span th:text="#{menu.administration.material}"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#"><span th:text="#{menu.administration.ontology}"></span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>

<div>
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <h2 th:text="#{material.search.title}"></h2>
    </div>
</div>

<script th:href="@{/js/vendor/jquery.js}"></script>
<script th:href="@{/js/foundation.min.js}"></script>
<script th:href="@{/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js}"></script>
<script th:href="@{/js/vendor/modernizr.js}"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready({
        jQuery(document).foundation();
    });
 </script>  

</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure my resources are being properly imported.

Also, I had to use `data-topbar="true"` because if I use `data-topbar` only, my page fails while rendering saying it a expecting for a `=` after the property name.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you so much for any help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was located in the property I was using to import my JS files.

As seen in my code, the import looks like this:

```
<script th:href="@{/js/foundation.min.js}"></script>
```

But to import a script file the `href` property is wrong, it must be `src` so the correct format is:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/foundation.min.js}"></script>
```

I know it was a silly mistake but I hope it helps someone else.

The fact that an error was never shown while compiling nor while generating the page worries me a little.

Answer (score 1):

your `th:text="#{menu.administration}` is not working

the structure should be

```
<h1 th:text="${header.title}">title</h1>

<small th:text="${header.subtitle}">Subtitle</small>
```

you can't leave the empty and expect a value

please take a look at the tutorial http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, I will try ti but I'm not sure about that being the problem. My  `th:text="#{menu.administration}"` is properly rendering a label taken from a *.properties file used for internationalization.